# scrollspy: how do I get it to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on this for hours, but can't get forward!
How do I make the tabs "active" when I scroll down and see the div and how do I make the tabs active by clicking them?
I usually make several pages where the tabs are active, but now I'm on the same page.

Is this correct?:
`$('body').scrollspy({target: '.tile'});`

http://jsfiddle.net/mellquist/3hXV2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3hXV2/2/)**

Every thing is fine you just forgot to add **bootstrap-scrollspy.js**

Even your tirger method is fine:

```
$('body').scrollspy({target: '.tile'});
```

You can use this **[CDN](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js)** to add scrollspy js.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
You made it work, but I now noticed that I had forgotten the link to bootstraps scrollspy.js:
`<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>`

Comment: i have just corrected my answer in case any one else read it in future.